# Should I switch 120 AC or 24 DC with a relay?

Tags: relay, switching

I would like to use a relay to switch power to an LED grow light. The grow light comes with an AC/DC adapter that takes mains US power and converts it to 24 VDC 1.8 A. Should I put a relay before the adapter or after the adapter? At work, we only use 12 and 24 VDC automotive relays so I've never actually had to pick.

Edit: I haven't picked the relay yet.

Comment: You can switch either side. If you switch the AC side then contact burns due to arcing at the contacts is minimal as the current switches through zero, quite often. And switching the AC side also means your adapter isn't using power when off. Which may be an advantage in your electricity bill. But switching DC can be done, too. And if so, it leaves your adapter powered and may mean the lights turn on a bit faster. (There are also secondary worries -- inrush currents might be one, for example. But that should give a few things toss into consideration.)

Comment: It it is a lot safer to switch the 24V DC. 1.8A is not a problem for a relay.

Comment: _"I would like to use a relay to switch power to an LED grow light."_ - Why?

Comment: setting up a light regime experiment for Begonias and need a way to programmatically control a 45W led grow light. @BruceAbbott

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If you are switching mains AC, you must follow some very  strenuous rules in terms of which **equipment** is used, and how it is installed on the mains side. I happen to be well-versed in those rules, so I don't mind at all :)

Not least, equipment (not components!) used in mains power must be UL listed and you must install it according to labeling and instructions, not RU component listed.  (A comparable NRTL may replace UL; CE is not one.)

In certain cases, it works out more favorably cost wise, for instance you can dive into the "parts bins" for furnace and HVAC. This can switch a lot of power (10kw) very cheaply ($35).

---

However, at this scale, on the 2A at 24VDC scale, you are better off entirely switching the low voltage.  You avoid the burdensome mains-wiring rules, and you can use cheap common low voltage DC relay **components** found at Mouser or Digi-Key, which are RU listed as components.  (RU is an Underwriter's Laboratories listing for components.)

Comment: RU listed wow that's a tell. even CSA.  Save Monica. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing if your ACDC supply has good soft start or DC enable it is probably less stressful to switch the 24Vdc 1.8A with either a transistor or relay using a reverse clamp diode on the coil and twisted pair for EMI reduction.